# -bash Mac OS X Lion "puts" returns "command not found"

Tags: unix, git, ruby

I'm trying to follow along with this [**tutorial**](http://gitimmersion.com/lab_05.html) and the `puts` command returns `command not found` and I am not sure why. I've followed this [**article**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-command-not-found-error-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it/) and looked in the various folders and do not see a `puts` command.

I've checked `echo $PATH` and everything seems to be in order and returns:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

My `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a command available to your shell. It's a command that's native to Ruby so you can only use it from within a Ruby script.

Answer (score 0):

"puts" is not a command in the terminal. It is like println() in java. You should have the line in your ruby file.
e.g.

```
puts "hello world"
```

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.